# how to not repeat same values when printing data frame?

Tags: r, printing, dataframe

I see that when Hadley Wickam prints data frame [here](http://had.co.nz/reshape/french-fries-demo.html), the values which **dont** change row over row **dont** get printed.

that is, instead of having :

> name      user       rating
>   robuchon  nicolas      2
>   robuchon  nicolas      1
>   robuchon  antoine      3
>   robuchon  tartenpion   2
>   gagnaire  nicolas      2
>   gagnaire  christophe   2

it prints as such :

> name      user       rating
>   robuchon  nicolas      2
>   ............................1
>   ...............antoine      3
>   ...............tartenpion   2
>   gagnaire  nicolas      2
>   ..............christophe   2

where the dots are for spaces...

Does anyone knows how to do that ?

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you are referring to, and I'm too impatient to watch the entire clip to try and figure it out...but I did notice he's wrapping `head()` around most of the commands...is that what you are referring to? If not, maybe take a screenshot of what it is you are talking about...or copy the command that is producing the output you want?

Comment: If you scroll to the last 1/5th of the demo you will see what he is asking. Executing the same commands produces different results on my console using current R and reshape. I get an error: `Error in NextMethod(x, ...) : invalid generic argument to NextMethod` when I attempt to explicitly apply print.cast_df to a cast dataframe.

Comment: HW has been developing tools very quickly.  There are significant differences between the `reshape` and `reshape2` packages, and he may be using yet another (development) version in the demo ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from the use of `cast()`.  The variables to the left of ~ are treated that way.

It must be a version of cast() that he is using because when he prints out non-cast data.frames, that behavior does not appear. Sorry, this answer doesn't completely answer your question.

Another reason I think it is another version of cast() is that instead of showing `(all)`, it shows `.`.  This feature also appears in a paper by the author in 2005.

Comment: what do you mean by that ? as far as I understand, a cast is just another dataframe...

Comment: may be he overloaded the print for "cast_df" classes.. I thought it was a general feature of R.

Comment: Maybe.  I'm not sure.  I would ask the author.

Comment: At least in some versions of `reshape` there is a `print.cast_df` and a `print.cast_matrix` ...